# Refreshing custom view in ListView android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I would like to learn about refreshing a custom view in a `ListView`. For example, lets say I have a custom view in a `LinearLayout` with `ProgressBar`. I am adding my custom view as a row in the `ListView`. Now whenever there is a change in any of  the `ProgressBar` in a row, I can see the whole `ListView` getting refreshed.

I enabled, the `"Show screen updates"` in `"Developer options"`. From this you can see the whole list view getting refreshed. I also checked with the `ICS` Media player list view, I can see the whole screen getting refreshed in the `ListView` of media player.

Is this the android default behavior in the `ListView` or am I doing something wrong? What about the performance if I load custom views in the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I believe, notifyDataSetChanged() is used when there is a change in the data items which is bound to an adapter. But my question here is about the View getting refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this--

```
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will refresh your list..

Answer (score 0):

if you want redraw view again just:
invalidate() your ListView